# Proper usage of the word since

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes I hear people say something like the example below. Is it correct to use the word *since* in this manner?

> Mosquitoes are surviving on earth since millions of years.

Comment: You need to be careful who you listen to! As StoneyB says, your example sentence is poor English for several reasons, and would never be produced by a native speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not correct. *Since* is employed to designate a timespan running from a **definite**<sup>†</sup> **point in time** up to the current 'Reference Time', whatever that may be:

> Bob has lived here **since** 1992. ... *The timespan runs from 1987 to the present.*
>
> In 1874 Wagner completed *Der Ring des Nibelungen*, which he had been working on **since** 1848. ... *The timespan runs from 1848 to 1874.*

If you want to define the timespan by its duration you should use *for*:

> Bob has lived here **for** twenty-two years.
>
> Wagner worked on the *Ring* **for** twenty-six years.
>
> Mosquitoes have survived on Earth **for** millions of years.

---

<sup>†</sup> This does not mean that the point must be defined with great precision. For instance, “Since the first millennium BCE” is acceptable.

Comment: What about "since millions of years ago"?

Comment: @JiK That's fine, because "millions of years ago" identifies a "point" in time: RightNow minus millions of years. It's a very **fuzzy** point, but it's a point :)

Comment: @StoneyB: Technically speaking I suppose you're right that "millions of years ago" identifies a "point" in time, so in principle it *could* be referenced by *since*. But precisely *because* it's such a "fuzzy" point in time, I'd have to say I don't like the usage much. Actually, if I'm honest, I don't think I'm keen on any variants of *since [some length of time] **ago***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't much like it either, but it's hard to know where you can draw a line that excludes "since MM of years ago" and includes "since the species arose MM of years ago".

Comment: Well, as it happens, all our examples are *since [some point in past time]*, but in practice it might make more sense to say the basic usage is *since [some prior **event**]*. Specific dates (1848, December, last Tuesday, etc.) are more easily envisaged as "events" (capable of being identified on a calendar) than something like *several years ago*. If @JiK is indeed a "learner", he's a very advanced one who probably doesn't need my advice on this specific issue, but for the benefit of anyone else who might read this thread, I think it's worth noting that ***we** [as natives]] don't like it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Lemme ruminate on that one ... my first reaction is that states work as well as events: "Since his youth", "Since Nixon was president".

Comment: I may be clutching at straws, but if the reference is to a *state*, doesn't it usually mean the relative precise point in time *when that state ended?* Or perhaps, *started*, which is what I'd probably understand by *"Mosquitoes have been around since dinosaurs roamed the earth"*. Maybe the problem is just that *since* and *ago* are a bit too much "the same, only different", so they just don't go well together.

Answer (score 2):

In your example sentence, for should be used in place of since.

*Since* is used when you are stating the start time(date/month/year/century etc.) of a duration in your sentence.

eg.

1. He has been playing **since five O'clock** in the morning
2. I have been working here **since 1991**.
3. This festival has been going on **since January**.

For is used when you are using the duration only in your sentence:

eg.

1. **Mosquitoes have survived on earth *for millions of years***
2. He has been playing **for five hours** straight.
3. I have been working here **for 10 years** now.
4. This festival has been going on **for past 2 months**

Comment: +1. But "is going" should be "has been going on".